# How to call two methods on one object in the same line

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods

I'm working on Ruby on Rails 4 and my project consists of having many Clients who have many Employees. I'm able to list the employee's first name and link it to the employee's profile.

What I was wanting to do is something along this logic:

```
<% @client.employees.each do |employee| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <%= link_to employee.name, employee.surname, employee %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

I want to list the Employee's first and last (surname) name for every list item and have it be one link. Is there any way to call two different methods on the same object in the same line? Thanks in advance your your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work for you.

```
<% @client.employees.each do |employee| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <%= link_to [employee.name, employee.surname].join(" "), employee %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

better way is to add a method in `helper` file which will handle the name display,  like this

```
module EmployeesHelper
  def render_employee_name(employee)
    [employee.name, employee.surname].join(" ")
  end
end
```

and in the view do this

```
<% @client.employees.each do |employee| %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <%= link_to render_employee_name(employee), employee %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i hope my answer will help you. incase of some clarification or issue. please comment.